# Search through contents of dictionary app mac

Tags: mac

I'm trying to remember a word and I know the precise description I read in the dictionary app on my mac: lacking in nuance or details. But it's not possible to search through the text of the dictionary app, it only accepts words as input.
Is there a way to search through the text anyways?